# netbeans + mercurial push to others

Tags: netbeans, mercurial, push, dvcs

I have 2 repos: at the Bitbucket and at my own server. Bitbucket repo is for testing and my own server is a production repo.

I have the following .hgrc contents:

```
[paths]
default = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/fancymedia/fancymedia-website
production = ssh://fancymedia@fancymedia.ru/www/fancymedia.ru/www
```

So the first line with "default" is for Bitbucket, the second one is a production path.
It allows me do a trick in a terminal like that:

```
hg push /* it makes a push to bibucket as a default path */
hg push production /* it pushes to my production server */
```

All i want is to do the same in Netbeans, yes i can make a push to a default path, but i can't push to my production server just using a short alias 'production', every time a have to type all the path to the server...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked in the [source for the Mercurial integration with NetBeans](http://hg.netbeans.org/main-silver/file/release71_base/mercurial/src/org/netbeans/modules/mercurial?style=paper) and it is not possible to extend the menu. It is simply [created](http://hg.netbeans.org/main-silver/file/release71_base/mercurial/src/org/netbeans/modules/mercurial/ui/menu/ShareMenu.java?style=paper) with a single menu item for "Push Other..." and "Pull Other...".

NetBeans only read the `default`, `default-push`, and `default-pull` values from the `[paths]` section in your `.hg/hgrc` file. I agree that it would have been smart to include other push/pull paths in the menu, but they're ignored.

This is as of NetBeans version 7.1, hopefully this changes in the future.